# knockout.js foreach position elements in rows

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Twitter Bootstrap template for my MVC4 single page application. My model view returns a list of 120 words. I'd like to position them in 10 rows of 12. The output markup should be similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span1">word1</div>
.
.
.
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span1">word13</div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

How would I accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach you can take, this example leveraged the MVVM pattern to parse out your twitter string and bind it to your view using template bindings: http://jsfiddle.net/KodeKreachor/78pvN/

Comment: sorry, this doesn't help much. This works if I get data in chunks of 12. I need this to work if I get one chunk of 120 and need to display in 10 rows.

Comment: No problem, I threw that example together pretty quick. All you'd have to do is split your twitter message string on the spaces and push them into the view model collections in groups of twelve.